# Which f(x) minimizes the order of g(f(x)) as x goes to infinity

Tags: big-o, limit, asymptotic-complexity, little-o

Assume f(x) goes to infinity as x tends to infinity and a,b>0. Find the f(x) that yields the lowest order for

[image]

as x tends to infinity.
By *order* I mean [Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and [Little o](http://math.wikia.com/wiki/Little-o_notation) notation.

I can only solve it roughly:

**My solution**: We can say ln(1+f(x)) is approximately equal to ln(f(x)) as x goes to infinity. Then, I have to minimize the order of

[image]

Since for any c>0, y+c/y is miminized when y =sqrt(c), b+ln f(x)}=sqrt(ax) is the anwer. Equivalently, f(x)=e^(sqrt(ax)-b) and the lowest order for g(x) is 2 sqrt(ax).

Can you help me obtain a rigorous answer?

Comment: @litelite edited the text accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rigorous way to minimize (I should say *extremize*) a function of another function is to use the *Euler-Lagrange relation*:

[image]

Thus:

[image]

Taylor expansion:

[image]

If we only consider up to "constant" terms:

[image]

Which is of course the result you obtained.

---

Next, linear terms:

[image]

We can't solve this equation analytically; but we can explore the effect of a *perturbation* in the function `f(x)` (i.e. a small change in parameter to the previous solution). We can obviously ignore any linear changes to `f`, but we can add a positive multiplicative factor `A`:

[image]

`sqrt(ax)` and `Af` are obviously both positive, so the RHS has a negative sign. This means that `ln(A) < 0`, and thus `A < 1`, i.e. the new perturbed function gives a (slightly) tighter bound. Since the RHS must be vanishingly small (`1/f`), `A` must not be very much smaller than 1.

Going further, we can add another perturbation `B` to the exponent of `f`:

[image]

Since `ln(A)` and the RHS are both vanishing small, the `B`-term on LHS must be even smaller for the sign to be consistent.

So we can conclude that (1) `A` is *very* close to 1, (2) `B` is *much* smaller than 1, i.e. the result you obtained is in fact a very good upper bound.

The above also leads to the possibility of even tighter bounds for higher powers of `f`.

Comment: Thank you for that.